# Uploading an image from local computer in a post is not working.

Tags: support, images

Uploading an image  (40kB) from local computer in a post is not working.

> Failed to upload image; couldn't reach imgur.

---

Update: Works now.

[image]

Comment: Possibly related bug report on [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/): [Failed to upload image; couldn't reach imgur (2020 edition)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353214). Can you check again to see if it works? The Meta SE post is tagged [status-completed].

Comment: To test the idea you might try navigating to imgur to make sure the network connectivity is there in a browser.  Details you might add to this post are: the graphic format you've chosen (.jpg, .gif, .png, etc.) and the platform (desktop vs. mobile, OS, etc.) you tried.